# How to Change context menu of windows Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-registry

i want to edit context menu of windows Explorer. and i want to create my own menu with sub menu as shown in image. and also do some task like copy and move to other destination. Can any one please show me how to do this with registry.

Is this possible or not? if it is possible please give me step by step answer.

```
Folder/file 
 -->Right click
    -->List of menu(Open,copy,send to,My menu name)
       -->My menu name ->(Copy,Move) 
          -->copy -->list of "fixed" folders or destination names
                     (They are already in my Hard disk) 
                     (On click on it it will perform copy operation).
```

Simply i want  to make sub-menu in context menu. and copy and move operation, and i want to display folders which i had created in my any drives. and also someone click on that folder it will perform copy operation.
[image: new menu]

Comment: For submenus you'd have to write a [shell extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144169(v=vs.85).aspx), AFAIK.

Comment: What's the operating system you're using?

Comment: A quick [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=context+menu+editor) turned up [some tools](http://www.maketecheasier.com/4-tools-edit-context-menu-windows/).

Comment: [Here](http://www.techtalkz.com/tips-n-tricks/4760-cutomize-right-click-context-menu-regedit-way.html)'s one that uses [regedit](https://www.google.com/search?q=regedit+context+menu)

Comment: I'm currently on windows 8.1 os @and31415

Comment: Can any one help me how to write shell extension in c#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Creating cascading menus

In Windows 7 and later you can create static menus directly through the registry.

> Because `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is a combination of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, you can register any custom verbs under the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` subkey. The main advantage of doing so is that elevated permission is not required.
>
> <sub>Source: [Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>

### Registry template

Here's a per-user registry template you can use. Just paste it in a new text document, and apply the changes you need. Then save it as a `.reg` file, and merge it to the registry. The custom menu will be added to all files and folders.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\MyMenu]
"MUIVerb"="My menu name"
"Position"="Bottom"
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\MyMenu\shell\cmd1]
@="Copy"
"AttributeMask"=dword:00000001
"AttributeValue"=dword:00000001
"ImpliedSelectionModel"=dword:00000000
"MUIVerb"="@shell32.dll,-31246"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\MyMenu\shell\cmd1\command]
@="copy command here"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\MyMenu\shell\cmd2]
@="Move"
"AttributeMask"=dword:00000002
"AttributeValue"=dword:00000002
"ImpliedSelectionModel"=dword:00000000
"MUIVerb"="@shell32.dll,-4145"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\MyMenu\shell\cmd2\command]
@="move command here"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Folder\shell\MyMenu]
"MUIVerb"="My menu name"
"Position"="Bottom"
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Folder\shell\MyMenu\shell\cmd1]
@="Copy"
"AttributeMask"=dword:00000001
"AttributeValue"=dword:00000001
"ImpliedSelectionModel"=dword:00000000
"MUIVerb"="@shell32.dll,-31246"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Folder\shell\MyMenu\shell\cmd1\command]
@="copy command here"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Folder\shell\MyMenu\shell\cmd2]
@="Move"
"AttributeMask"=dword:00000002
"AttributeValue"=dword:00000002
"ImpliedSelectionModel"=dword:00000000
"MUIVerb"="@shell32.dll,-4145"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Folder\shell\MyMenu\shell\cmd2\command]
@="move command here"
```

### Remarks

> - The `AttributeMask` value specifies the [SFGAO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762589(v=vs.85).aspx) value of the bit values of the mask to test with.
> - The `AttributeValue` value specifies the [SFGAO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762589(v=vs.85).aspx) value of the bits that are tested.
> - The `ImpliedSelectionModel` specifies zero for item verbs, or nonzero for verbs on the background shortcut menu.
>
> <sub>Source: [Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>

In the template above, the `AttributeMask` and `AttributeValue` are set to `0x00000001` and `0x00000002`, respectively. Those values are associated to the `SFGAO_CANCOPY` and `SFGAO_CANMOVE` constants, which determine whether the specified items can be copied/moved.

### Further reading

- [Creating Static Cascading Menus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: IMPORTANT: This is not entirely true. The command is not specified with "@" under cmd1 but there is an additional subkey called "command" and the command is specified in this default value

Comment: @divB Absolutely. I've fixed the template, thanks for pointing it out.